# Composition of a rotation and translation is a rotation with what angle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, rotations

> Im trying to figure out what degree exactly you get when you first
>   translate and then rotate or the other way around.

*I'm trying it without coordinates in the Euclidian plane.*

Let $\delta\in Iso(\mathbb{E})$ a Rotation at Point $P\in\mathbb{E}$ with the angle $2\alpha$ and $\tau=\sigma_b\circ\sigma_a$ ($a\parallel b)$ an Translation.

There exists an $c\perp b$ with $P\in c$ so that we can express the rotation as $\delta=\sigma_d\circ\sigma_c$ with $\sphericalangle(c,d)=\alpha$. This leads to:

$$\delta\circ\tau=\sigma_d\circ\sigma_c\circ\sigma_b\circ\sigma_a$$

Because of $b\perp c$, the composition $\sigma_c\circ\sigma_b=\sigma_b\circ\sigma_c$ comutate .
$$\delta\circ\tau=\sigma_d\circ\sigma_b\circ\sigma_c\circ\sigma_a$$

Now $\sigma_c\circ\sigma_a$ and $\sigma_d\circ\sigma_b$ form rotations, whose product is an rotation itself.
Because $a\parallel b$ and $b\perp c$ follows $a\perp c$, so $\sigma_a\circ\sigma_c$ forms a rotation with angle $\pm\pi$.
So $\sigma_d\circ\sigma_b$ is an rotation with angle $2\sphericalangle(b,d)$.
Therefore the composition of both leads to an rotation with angle $\pi+2\sphericalangle(b,d)$.

Because of the fact, that the lines $b,c,d$ gives us a rectangular triangle the angle $\sphericalangle(b,d)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha$.

This leads to the result, that $\delta\circ\tau$ is an Rotation with the angle $2\pi-2\alpha\equiv-2\alpha$ (mod $2\pi$).

> Is this correct so far? Whats about the algebraic sign?

If we take a look at the reversed composition, we choose an $d'\perp a$ and $P\in d'$ so that $\delta=\sigma_{d'}\circ\sigma_{c'}$ with $\sphericalangle(c',d')=\alpha$.
This leads to:

$$\tau\circ\delta=\sigma_{b}\circ\sigma_{a}\circ\sigma_{d'}\circ\sigma_{c'}=\sigma_{b}\circ\sigma_{d'}\circ\sigma_{a}\circ\sigma_{c'}$$

From the fact that $a,d',c'$ forms a rectangular triangle we derive:
$$\pi=\sphericalangle(c',a)+\sphericalangle(a,c')=\sphericalangle(c',a)+(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha)\Leftrightarrow\sphericalangle(c',a)=\pi-(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha)=\frac{\pi}{2}+\alpha$$

This leads to an Rotation $\tau\circ\delta$ with the angle $\pi+\pi+2\alpha\equiv2\alpha$ (mod $2\pi$).

> I dont loose the feeling that there is a sign-error somewhere. Is it correct hat the reverse-composition leads to an oposite rotationangle?

Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: I don't understand any of what you wrote, but translation never changes the amount of rotation. A rotation by $\theta$ followed by a translation is still a rotation by $\theta$ (around a different point), and the same is true for a translation followed by a rotation of $\theta$. This is because if you take two points $a$ and $b$ which are mapped to $a'$ and $b'$, then $\theta$ is just the angle between the vectors $b-a$ and $b'-a'$, and translation doesn't change that.

Comment: Thanks thats a pretty easy visualiziation of one side of the problem and seems to confirm my feeling of an sign-error( because i get an $-\alpha$) But what about a rotation followed by a translation, meens $\tau\circ\delta$? In this case your argument do not work.

Comment: Why doesn't it work?

Comment: I was foolish. U are right! Wenn i first rotate the vectors $a-b$ by $\theta$ and then translate it, we get a vector $a'-b'$, those angel with $a-b$ is also $\theta$.